# IB Math AAHL Logarithm problem

Tags: logarithms

We've been doing logarithms recently and I'm having some trouble with this question:

Find the value of $x$ given that

$$\log_2 x+\log_2 x^2+\log_2 x^3 +\ldots+\log_2 x^m = 3m(m+1)$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: Use $\log_2 x^k=k\log_2 x$.

Comment: Also, for any base $~b \in \Bbb{R+},~$ and any $~x,y \in \Bbb{R^+},~$ you have that $$\log_b(x) + \log_b(y) = \log_b(x \times y).$$

Answer (score 0):

One rule of logarithms is:

$$\log_a{b^c} = c \log_a{b}$$

So let's apply that here:

$$\log_2 x + 2 \log_2 x + ... + m \log_2 x = 3m(m+1)$$

Factorizing:

$$\log_2 x \bigg(1+2+...+m\bigg)= 3m(m+1)$$

Using the sum of natural numbers:

$$\frac{m(m+1)\log_2 x}{2} = 3m(m+1)$$

Simplifying...

$$\log_2 x = 6$$

$$x = 2^6$$